# How can I run Ranorex automated tests from MTM?

Tags: .net, tfs, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager, ranorex

I am trying to somehow connect Microsoft Test Manager and Ranorex together.

what i have done till now is, I created a ranorex automated test with ranorex recoder, it seems to be OK.

I added this ranorex project to Visual Studio and added a CodedUI Test project which got a reference from the ranorex project.

I can run this test from visual studio with code.

what I really want is to associate this automated test from ranorex with the test cases defined in MTM so I can run from MTM.

I did associate the test with CodedUI test, but each time I run a test a i get an Exception which says: could not find the testsuit.rxtst..... everytime a new folder is created and there no files in it.

seems kindda imposible for me .

any Idea?

thanx in advanced

well I tried to post an Image, but i need atleast 10 repus :(

Comment: Here is the recommendation from Ranorex: https://www.ranorex.com/blog/running-ranorex-automated-tests-using-microsoft-test-manager/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to add the DeploymentItem attribute to either your CodedUITest class or your test method.

```
<CodedUITest()>
<DeploymentItem("NameOfYourTestSuite.rxtst")>
Public Class NameOfClassContainingCodedUITests
```

or

```
<TestMethod()>
<DeploymentItem("NameOfYourTestSuite.rxtst")>
Public Sub NameOfTestMethod()
```

Don't forget to also deploy your module groups if you have used this feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you can run your Ranorex tests from a CodedUI Test, then you can associate the CodedUI test with an MTM Test Case.

You need to open the Test Case work item in Visual Studio (with your CodedUI project open), then click the Associate Automation button and pick the CUIT Test to associate.

[image]

Comment: Tanx Dylan, but I did it, each time I run a test a i get an Exception which says: could not find the testsuit.rxtst.....
everytime a new folder is created and there no files in it.

Comment: Make sure the items have the property set to "Always copy". Otherwise, deployment items will be ignored.